# Numbers of JVMs per JBoss server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jvm

I'm wondering if the number of JVMs for a JBoss server can be increased? Not sure if each of the application can run on its own JVM. If this is possible, what are the advantages of having more than one JVMs in a single server.

Comment: JBoss / Tomcat run in a JVM. If you want 2 instances of JBoss, you could have them (running in separate JVMs). You could have a common DB accessed by both and a load balancer to manage requests to this server.

Answer (score 1):

Each JBoss instance runs on its own JVM. Very often for scalability and high availability (HA) purposes, you will have N+1 JBoss instances (and N+1 JVMs accordingly) in your architecture.

This provides you many benefits, most notably your HTTP/HTTPs web thread pool is increased (if the underlying OS/VMs hardware are beefy enough) so you can handle 2x as many requests concurrently, bigger EJB thread pool along with HA, clustered single sign on, session replication across nodes, and many other benefits. Typically you will also have one or more software load balancer such as apache HTTPD proxying the requests to individual JBoss worker nodes via mod-cluster or mod-jk.